# Data Paging With Pure AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, datagrid

I have a Flash Datagrid component being populated by data from Robotlegs services. However as the datagrid needs to show more and more rows of info I need to implement a way of loading the data as it is needed. Ideally this will be as the user scrolls down the list, I have seen this in Flex examples but I could do with a pure AS3 solution. Does anyone have any guidance or ideas how to approach this?

Here is the Flex example: http://www.jamesward.com/2010/10/11/data-paging-in-flex-4/

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused.  You realize that Flex is an ActionScript 3 framework, right? So everything in Flex is "all ActionScript".  MXML exists as almost as a helper to generate ActionScript code.  The DataGrid is a Flex components, built all in ActionScript. You can't really make modifications to the DataGrid w/o using Flex.  So what, exactly, are you trying to do?  Build a non-Flex DataGrid? Or something else?

Comment: I see what your saying, I should have explained in more detail...

Comment: I don't want the increased file size of the Flex framework as the full project only uses pure AS3 and no MXML at all...the root of the application is Sprite not a Flex Application. Is there a way of using a Flex DataGrid inside of an application root which extends Sprite?

Comment: The Additional Size of the Flex Project is due to the Flex framework; which includes a lot of "Boiler" plate classes to initialize and setup the framework and handle layout and styling. It is not due to MXML.  You cannot use a Flex component--including the DataGrid--without those framework classes that handle the "Framework stuff".  You can write your own code to setup the Flex Framework classes (sounds real hard to me).  Or you could write your own versions of those classes to simulate the Flex Framework without actually using the Flex Framework (sounds real hard to me).

Comment: Or you could write your own non-Flex based DataGrid (sounds hard to me).  You may want to search around for DataGrid components that are not Flex based.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to extend the Flash DG to use something like an AsyncListView and look at the AsyncListView to see how it does it, then write it to generate the correct events when an item isn't found, but remove any dependencies to Flex. You'll also need to do something that acts like the Responder class to support having different overlapping calls to the same service.